# ORA-00979 - not a group by expression - join and count

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by

I have two sql SQL queries, and both are working. But I need to combine the two queries in a single one, and my try does not work.
These are the working queries:

```
from z35
inner join z13
on z35.z35_rec_key=z13.z13_rec_key
where z35_event_type='80' 

select count(z35_event_type) as pocet, z35_rec_key 
from z35 
where z35_event_type='80' 
group by z35_rec_key
```

I try to combine then in this way, but I am getting an error:

```
select count(z35_event_type) as Total, z35_rec_key, z13.z13_title 
from z35 join z13
on z35.z35_rec_key=z13.z13_rec_key where z35_event_type='80'
group by z35_rec_key
```

The error is: `ORA-00979 - not a group by expression`

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to make more comprehensible for english speaking people. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case my guess is wrong. And note that in the first sample the `select` part is missing. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you can fix this by putting both keys in the `group by`:

```
select count(z35_event_type) as Total, z35_rec_key, z13.z13_title 
from z35 join
     z13
     on z35.z35_rec_key=z13.z13_rec_key
where z35_event_type='80'
group by z35_rec_key, z13.z13_title;
```

That will fix your syntax problem.  Whether is does what you want is another issue, because you have not described what you really want to do.

Comment: Super! Thank you so much. It works perfectly. I did not realize that I had to use two columns in the group .

Comment: Curious, does anyone know why this would be downvoted?

Comment: Someone who uses an RDBMS that is not so strict about group by, and thinks this answer is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

z13.z13_title - is not in the GROUP BY clause